# How to add a bibtex file in beamer which shows the references in last slide

Tags: bibtex

I have a bibtex file which I used for writing my thesis in LaTex. Now I want to use same "reference.BibTex" file to show the list of references in last slide of my Beamer presentation. Can someone enlighten me how can it be done?

Comment: Two comments: (a) Unless you want to bore your audience to tears, don't show a slide, *not a single slide*, with formatted bibliographic entries as part of your `beamer` presentation. Not even at the very end of the presentation. Repeat: Don't do it. (b) Are you familiar with `\cite`-like commands, the `\nocite{*} command, and with running BibTeX?

Comment: @Mico.....I do not want to cite any reference. I just want to have a slide (at the end of presentation) which could show the list of references or documents which I have used for current presentation.

Comment: My comments were not about citation call-outs -- although they apply to them as well -- but about the formatted bibliography. If you really must show a list of the main works that you consulted for your thesis, just create a bullet-point list by hand. For each item, state only the author(s)' surnames (no first names), the title of the publication (suitably abbreviated, if necessary), and the year of publication. Omit all details about publishers, addresses, editors of conference volumes, journal names, volume and issue numbers for articles published in journals, and page numbers. Be selective!

Comment: @Mico's comments are one (nice clear) viewpoint.  Here's another: If you're planning to put the slides up for download, have good references at the end, but don't present this slide (it keeps them in the same file). I also think that there's no point putting up a reference if the reader doesn't have the information to track it down; an abbreviated title combined with a common author name can be really annoying.

Comment: ... it also depends on the type of presentation.  A conference talk of 10-20 minutes is very different to a research group seminar.  In the latter you may well want to have full references at your fingertips.  Though you still shouldn't plan on presenting them.  At one point this was looking like a good use of QR codes, but the combination of using QR codes to transmit malicious URLs and some conferences saying "no photos of the talks" seems to have halted that

Answer (score 4):

The `\nocite{my_cite}` command will not print the reference on the slide, while still considering it for the bibliography.

An working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

% Removes icon in bibliography
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}

\author{Obi Wan Kenobi}
\title{The Phantom Menace}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}   
I would like to cite no one.\nocite{HanSolo1983}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
% This prints the bibliography on the slide
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\nocite{HanSolo1983}` will be much more sutied for the job. Alternatively, `\nocite{*}` adds all entries from the database to the reference list.

Comment: So a thesis.bib used for a presentation probably *shouldn't* include `\nocite{*}` unless you want dozens of sides of references. (@Johannes_B)

Comment: @ChrisH A presentian most certainly not. Not at the end. As a footnote, abrigded, when needed. Maybe a handout with the full list if requested.